# How to fix this json encode from database

Tags: php, arrays, json, xcode

I am working on JSON arrays. I have done this:

> [{"id":"12","text":"Technophile 1 (Branch 1)"},{"id":"29","text":"Brunei Darussalam"}{"id":"135","text":"Entern (abc)"}]

but as per criteria I want it in this way:

> {"results":[{"id":"9","text":"Technophile 1 (Branch 1)"},{"id":"22","text":"Entern (abc)"}]}

Meaning there should be `{"result":` in the starting and `}` in the end of this json.

Here is my code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'select2');
$sql = "SELECT countries.id, countries.title FROM countries 
    WHERE title LIKE '%".$_GET['term']."%'
    LIMIT 10"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$json = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $json[] = ['id'=>$row['id'], 'text'=>$row['title']];
}  
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: echo json_encode(array("results"=>$json))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is add the data to an array.

```
echo json_encode(['results' => $json]);
```

Comment: This answer is OK but you can improve it by adding link to the `json_encode` command and explain the connection between PHP array and json object